# How can I plot the data from a table when the x column gives the difference between x values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, charts

I want to create a "Trial Profile" chart with Ti*k*Z.

My data is as follows: Height (Y axis) and time between checkpoints (X axis).

```
     y      x
     0      0
    10      3
    20      3
    40      8
    30      6
```

An important feature is vertical lines connecting checkpoints (x) and heights  (y).

The result should look something like this
 (Orange data are in informational purposes only):

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: The best way to generate graphs is using the [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en) package, which is based on Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 3):

Start reading `pgfplots` manual Section 4.5

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[ycomb,scatter] table[x=x,y=y]{
     y      x
     0      0
    10      3
    20      3
    40      8
    30      6
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Altough he put no effort in writing the question (so nice of you to answer :P), it might be an acceptable question, since you could consider the main issue not “Do this for me” but “How can I plot the data from a table when the `x` column gives the *difference* between `x` values”. In any case, your answer doesn't plot what the OP intended.